# Why am I receiving this SQLException error stating that no suitable driver can be found?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sqlexception

I'm on a mac, running a MAMP instance of MySQL. I'm trying to use a jdbc driver to connect my java code to a database called 'test', working with a table called 'customer.' I keep getting an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/test
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with my code, or if it's a configuration problem with the MAMP instance of MySQL, or if it's something else entirely.

I have an initialize driver method:

```
public void initializeDriver(){
     try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      }
     catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
     }

 }
```

And I have a connection created in the following way:

```
public void insertCustomer(String connectionUrl, String connectionUser, String connectionPassword, Customer customer) {

         try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
            Statement constat = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, email, deliverable, create_date) VALUES (" + customer.id + ", " + customer.emailAddress + ", " + customer.deliverable + ", " + customer.createDate + ")" ;
            constat.executeQuery(query);
            conn.close();

         }
         catch(SQLException e){
             System.out.println(e.toString());
         }


     }
```

And I have downloaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.20 and set it in my classpath.

If anyone has any suggestions for how I could correct this error, I would be really grateful!

Answer (score 2):

You have to put [MySQL jdbc connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) jar library into the classpath.

Then initialize the driver before opening the connection with code like the following :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Comment: Oh, I should have said in my question that I have done so. I'll edit it to reflect that, thanks.

Comment: Have you initialized the driver before using it ? this kind of error message is due to the fact that the driver is not found on the system ...

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing with my initializedriver method - is that not correct?

Comment: You have to call the initialization of the driver before opening the connection, see my updated answer ...

Comment: Using `.newInstance()` is not necessary (not since Java 1.1 btw). And with a JDBC 4.0 compliant driver it is no longer necessary to load the driver yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the corresponding mysql JDBC driver jar in your classpath or loadable by your container. See the [doc for ConnectorJ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j.html) and note the installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add *mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar* to Glassfish (or Tomcat) *lib* folder.

Answer (score 0):

you have also a error in this row

```
    constat.executeQuery(query);
```

if you want insert some data in data base you have to use this code

```
constat.executeUpdate(query);
```